# How can I run phpunit commands from any location in CLI?

Tags: magento2, cli, phpunit, integration-test, filesystem

In [Magento 2 documentation "Running Unit Tests in the CLI"](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/test/unit/unit_test_execution_cli.html) is text:

> To run all tests, navigate to the Magento base directory and execute
> the following command:
>
> $ ./vendor/bin/phpunit -c dev/tests/unit/phpunit.xml.dist

My question is: **How can I run unit tests or integration tests without navigating to specific Magento directory?**

*So basically I would like to know the reason, why I have to be in specific directory to run phpunit commands in CLI? (I want to execute the command from **any** location)*

**EDITED:**

Why I can not use full path to the vendor/bin/phpunit directory?

```
<path to Magento base directory>/vendor/bin/phpunit -c dev/tests/unit/phpunit.xml
```

*ERROR THAT IT RETURNS:*
Could not read "dev/tests/unit/phpunit.xml". **Why the error appears?**

**Example:** why I can not run `/var/www/magento2/vendor/bin/phpunit -c dev/tests/unit/phpunit.xml` when I am situated in `/var/www/magento2/var/log $` location or anywhere else in the file system?

***Reason:** I want to create an app that allows me to speed up my development process. **(I am not interested IDE-s)** and I want to understand the reason why I have to navigate to the Magento base directory.*

Comment: I will add this link to other users here: [Chapter 3. The Command-Line Test Runner](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/textui.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHPUnit is installed by Composer, so it's executable is in the `/vendor/bin` directory. If you want to be able to run that program from anywhere in the command line, you need to add it to your path. Assuming you don't already have another version of `phpunit` installed globally, there are a couple of ways to do this:

1. If you run `export PATH=$PATH:/var/www/magento2/vendor/bin` it will only last for the length of the session.
2. You can permanently change it by adding that line to your `~/.bashrc` file: `export PATH=$PATH:/var/www/magento2/vendor/bin`
3. I think you can also create a symlink to `phpunit` to the `/bin` directory, but it's not best practice: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116508/adding-to-path-vs-linking-from-bin
4. Install `phpunit` globally another way (`PEAR`?), and don't use the version that M2 installs via Composer.

So now you can run Magento's `phpunit` anywhere. But you still need to pass the correct configuration to it.

Each test suite in Magento (unit, functional, etc) has a slightly different configuration, which is why you might pass it in via the `-c dev/tests/unit/phpunit.xml.dist` parameter, as you did in your example.

But if you rename `phpunit.xml.dist` to `phpunit.xml`, and if you run `phpunit` in the `dev/tests/unit/` directory, it should automatically use the `phpunit.xml` file in that directory. This saves some typing.

What I would recommend is adding `vendor/bin` to your PATH, so you can run `phpunit` anywhere, then `cd` in to the test folder you want to run, rename the config files `phpunit.xml`, run your tests suites in those directories, for the shortest command.

You will still need to type out the full path to the actual tests you want to run, though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I want to know why I can not use full path to the vendor/bin/phpunit directory?

Comment: What directory are you running the tests from? The Magento root?

Comment: Make sure this file exists, too: `ls dev/tests/unit/phpunit.xml` If you haven't renamed `phpunit.xml.dist` to `phpunit.xml` you will get the `Could not read` error, obviously.

Comment: The file that @thaddeusmt pointed out phpunit.xml exists and when following the documentation all works. (The documentation does not answer my question).

Comment: I'm still trying to understand your question I guess - if you are in the Mage root (`cd /var/www/magento2` let's say), and the file `/var/www/magento2/dev/tests/unit/phpunit.xml` exists, and phpunit is installed in `/var/www/magento2/vendor/bin/phpunit`, and you run `vendor/bin/phpunit -c dev/tests/unit/phpunit.xml` - you are getting an error still?

Comment: I would want to know in my question: why I have to be in the Magento root? Why I can not run those commands anywhere else in file system? Example: why I can not run `/var/www/magento2/vendor/bin/phpunit -c dev/tests/unit/phpunit.xml` when I am located in `/var/www/magento2/var/log $` location or anywhere else in the file system?

Comment: You should be able to run the commands anywhere - but you'll need to use the full path to the `phpunit.xml` as well:  `/var/www/magento2/vendor/bin/phpunit -c /var/www/magento2/dev/tests/unit/phpunit.xml`

Comment: It works. Sorry I did not notice to change the phpunit.xml to full path